# Why gluPerspective gives a result that does not match the formula in the documentation?

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, perspectivecamera

Return of `gluPerspective` differ from formula in documentation

Formula for `gluPerspective` described in [IBM-doc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=library-gluperspective-subroutine) and [Khronos doc](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) is

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f/aspect | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | f | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | (far + near) / (near - far) | (2 * far + near) / (near-far) |
| 0 | 0 | -1 | 0 |

but when I check gluPerspective matrix with python:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
gluPerspective(fov_h, aspect_ratio, near, far)
projection_matrix = glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX)
```

result seems too look like:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f/aspect | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | f | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | (far + near) / (near - far) | -1 |
| 0 | 0 | (2 * far + near) / (near-far) | 0 |

For e.g. parameters `gluPerspective(45.0, 4/3, 0.1, 100)` returns:

[[ 1.8106601  0.         0.         0.       ]

[ 0.         2.4142137  0.         0.       ]

[ 0.         0.        -1.002002  -1.       ]

[ 0.         0.        -0.2002002  0.       ]]

So:

- why?
- which formula is correct?

Comment: Maybe the output is in column major order rather than row major order.

Comment: OpenGL matrices are column-major order matrices. So what you write row by row in the tables of your answer are actually columns. Just because they look like rows in the debugger dump doesn't mean they are rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the formula is correct and the problem here is your interpretation of the output. My guess is that the output is shown in so-called column major order. You are assuming that the output is row major order, but that isn't the case. See [this wikepedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) for an explanation of the difference.

Comment: that's make sense.
If then, Should i use first or second formula to make numpy array if i send matrix to Uniform using `glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, matrix)`. I mean, last row i np.array should be [0,0,-1,0] or [0,0,(2 * far + near) / (near-far),0]?

Comment: @Maciej_Adamski What are you trying to accomplish? Are you implementing these formula yourself? If you need a numpy array, can you just do `np.array(projection_matrix)` to get it rather than doing the formula youself?

Comment: @Maciej_Adamski Note that if you do `np.array([1, 2],[3,4])`, It is up to you to decide what are "columns" and what are "rows". There is nothing in python or numpy that dictates that `[1,2]` is the first "row". You can just as easily call this the first "column". This means that you can do the formula in whatever way you want. You just have to be consistent in what are the "rows" and what are the "columns". This is the whole point of having "row major order" and "column major order". Which interpretation you use is entirely up to you.

Comment: @Maciej_Adamski Bringing this back to the perspective matrix, the last **row** is `[0,0,-1,0]` and the last **column** is `[0,0,(2 * far + near) / (near-far),0]`. When you ask, what the last row should be, there is no choice. The choice is whether you are storing the numpy array in row major order or column major order.

Comment: It's working now, and terrain shows correctly with perspective projection. Thanks!